# jQuery перехват submit

Tags: jquery, submit

Тупой вопрос:

```
    $(".payment-form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
//какие то действия
        $(this).submit();
    });
```

Приводит к ошибке в консоли... Подскажите, что не так ? Форма нормальная.

Ошибка:

```
jquery-1.8.3.js:3937 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at Function.Sizzle [as find] (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js:3937:26)
    at init.find (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js:5385:11)
    at init (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js:163:38)
    at jQuery (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js:44:10)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/1%20(2).html:39:20)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js:3058:9)
    at HTMLFormElement.eventHandle (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js:2676:28)
    at Object.trigger (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js:2941:12)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js:3599:17)
```

Comment: какая именно ошибка?

Comment: Добавил в пост.

Comment: Подождите вы в submit вызываете его снова?

Comment: Я отлавливаю сабмит, мне нужно провести какие действия по замене inputов  а потом снова отправить форму. Как быть?

Comment: Либо не прерывайте стандартную отправку (то есть уберите `e.preventDefault();`), либо отправляйте данные Ajax-ом. `$(this).submit();` нужно убрать в обоих случаях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы написали называется [Рекурсией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.92_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.BC.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B8)

Форма:

```js
    $(".payment-form").submit(function () {
            alert($("#textinput").val()); //0
            $("#textinput").val('new value');
            alert($("#textinput").val()); //new value

            return true; //отправляете ваш submit
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="action" method="post" class="payment-form">
   <input type="text" id="textinput" value="0">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Отправляется новое значение

Comment: Про рекурсию понял. Но так не отправится. Сделал вообщем вторую скрытую форму и ее сабмичу.

Comment: верно вам тогда не нужно делать `e.preventDefault();` уберите его и тогда форма отправится после изменений

Comment: Тогда в таком случае форма уйдет с дефолтными данными,а я собираю данные...

Comment: Изменил ответ  ..

Comment: Спасибо. Думал что все таки форма будет уходить с дефолтными данными, но проверил php скриптом - все ок )